# Stack View example from the book "Beginning iOS 9 Programming with Swift"

Tags: ios, xcode7

So I was following the textbook instruction (beginning ios 9 programming with swift) from Chapter 6 to learn Stack View in Swift. However, I can't get the example to work. The image is just not displayed correctly in any version of simulator. So this is a vertical stack view with two constraints, "vertical spacing to top layout guide" and "center horizontally in container".

Any suggestions or similar problems that got solved?

Thanks!

Below are the wrong and right images:
[image: Wrong image (my view)]
[image: Right image (book view)]

Comment: Do you have any warnings ? Try to set a width to your image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, get your wardRobe label with this setting, I set the Font size to 40, you can customize the way you want.

[image]

**Second**, get the other label like so :

[image]

Again, you can customize the settings of the label

Next, set the width of the two to be the same so that it looks like this:

[image]

Awesome, time for introducing player of the game, The Stack View:
Click on the button in your main storyboard (see below)

[image]

Next, click one of your labels and hold command, then select the other label too. (Both labels should be selected together). Next, click on this button in your storyboard:
Your stack view should look something like this :

[image]

Now, to resize the image, tick select the width and height and type in the desired values, and click add constraint: 
[image]

Now, go to your view hierarchy and click **add missing constraints**, and you are done!

It should say, **no layout issues like so**
[image]

Update: Resolving auto lay out across different configurations:

Select your stackView like so:
[image]

Next, tick **Horizontally in container** and then **add 1 constraint**

[image]

Finally, go to view hierarchy and click fix misplacement. That should sort everything

[image]

Final preview
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, there is always a misplaced view issue in the view controller. It says for the Label "Keep your wardrobe organized", "Expected: y = 60" "Actual: y = 61". Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Hey, when you set the widths of the two labels equal (as in image 3), after doing that make sure that the coordinates of the two arent overlapping by checking attributes inspector. Xcode has an error of +/- 1 with the blue lines.

Comment: Hi there, how do you tell if they r overlapping or not? What field do I look into attributes inspector? I see coordinates in the size inspector. Thanks.

Comment: If a view occupies space in y domain from say 30 to 60, then the view right on the top of it  should start from 61, and not 60.. 
if a view ends at 60 and another view start at 60. Then both of them occupy 60, hence they overlap.

Comment: Ya, I'm pretty sure they r not overlapping. Anyways, i cant get the yellow warning to go away. Another funny thing is that the view looks okay in the simulator (when you click the play button), but it doesn't display correctly in the preview option (it's missing the label with text of "Wardrobe", for some reason...). Do you have idea why is this happening?

Comment: This means that there might be some issue with auto layout. Please wait, I will try to check and if I find anything, I will update this answer

Comment: check update @JACKZHANG. And if this post helped you, I'd be glad if you upvote and make the answer correct :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113173/discussion-between-akshansh-thakur-and-jack-zhang).